# Spring Boot Security XML vs WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for CSRF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am migrating my Spring Application to Spring Boot.

I have an extensive security.xml file which maps all my controller code to the different Authentication Providers.

I know I can create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and convert them to code, however, its not possible in the short term.

I can use the `security.xml` with `ImportResource` and works but all my controllers return back a `CSRF Error`

I tried making a class as this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And Spring Boot Application

```
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:security.xml"})
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
```

Now when I remove the `ImportResource`, the CSRF disable in `WebSecurityConfig` works, but if I have it doesn't work.

I tried adding the `csrf disabled = true` tag under `<http>` tag in my xml file but it is not working.

Any way to disable CSRF in Spring Boot using XML or somehow get it to consider both the XML and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class?

Comment: first, are you sure you want to disable csrf?

Comment: Yes my backend is a pure API, no website ever hits it, only used by internal services

Comment: Did you try with ConfigurationPostProcessor (http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06.html). There are tutorials online. Haven't tested it with security, though. Worth a shot.

Comment: Could not figure it out :(. Just went with migrating XML schema to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the tag

```
[sec:csrf disabled="true"][/sec:csrf]
```

in your xml config